# React native: MapView create lag in when modal view is presented

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a modal view presented that have a MapView in it. There's a noticeable lag when presenting the view since the MapView takes quite some performance to render.

What can I do to make it smoother? Preload? Load it async? etc..

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `InteractionManger.runAfterInteractions()` to track when the animation is complete, then render the MapView. See https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/interactionmanager.html for details on how interaction manager works.

Answer (score 1):

in React Native docs. they say you can load heavy subComponent when you Component has mounted. you can render mapComponent after the modal has mounted. have a look at official recomment  [at there](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance.html#slow-navigator-transitions)